# Appending a const QString & to QStringList

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a slot that returns a const QString:

```
QStringList listErr;

connect(this->restService.data(), &CommonToolkit::RestService::RestSuccess,
        [=](int code, const QString &error_message, const QString &data){

    listErr << data;
}
```

I get the error:

```
passing 'const QStringList' as 'this' argument of 'QStringList& QStringList::operator<<(const QString&)' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
             listErr << data;
```

Doing research on Google, I see why the error is happening.  My question is how can I convert the const variable so that I can add it to the QStringList?  I can't seem to find information on this.

Thanks

Comment: It's not the `const QString &data` that needs "converted", it's the mode by which you capture the `QStringList listErr`. Hopefully this code has been ellipsised unrealistically, because otherwise capturing a reference to an automatically allocated object in the same scope and then stashing it in a slot looks suspect. If the slot outlives the `QStringList`, bad times are inevitable. Either way, you should post full, compilable code, not an ambiguous fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are going to modify the value of listErr you have to use `&` instead of `=`:

According to the [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

> [&] captures all automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by
>   reference and current object by reference if exists
>
> [=] captures all  automatic variables used in the body of the lambda by copy and current
>    object by reference if exists

---

```
QStringList listErr;

connect(this->restService.data(), &CommonToolkit::RestService::RestSuccess,
        [&](int code, const QString &error_message, const QString &data){

    listErr << data;
}
```

Comment: (so long as we infer that `listErr` doesn't go out of scope before the slot does, which is presumably only implied here because the code sample is a toy one)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  This was what was missing.

Comment: @eyllanesc I don't see how that follows. Do you mean because of the `const` and `this` in the error? It's considered `const` by the lambda because by-value capture creates a copy as a member of the lambda, and the lambda's `operator()` is `const` by default. Whether the `QStringList` were a member of the connecting class wouldn't make any difference to this, at least that I can fathom. Although, yes, that would stand to prevent any feet being shot off due to a dangling reference. :)

Comment: Also, if it were a member, and the connection were made in a `const` method, you couldn't modify it via a by-reference capture. But I might've just completely misunderstood what you inferred from the error, so my bad if so!